# Hide ColumnFilter by hitting enter in ColumnFilterFormElement in primeng

Tags: primeng, primeng-table

On my primeng table I have added some column filters. These filters have a input field. What I want to do is hide the ColumnFilter when hitting enter while the input field has focus.
I try to do this by overwriting the `onTextInputEnterKeyDown` of `ColumnFilterFormElement` like so:

```
ColumnFilterFormElement.prototype.onTextInputEnterKeyDown = function (e: any) {
  //hide ColumnFilter somehow
}
```

In the context of that method `this` points to the ColumnFilterFormElement which has focus. ColumnFilterFormElement has a property `colFilter` which I assume is its parent Filter element. However that property is private so I cant use that reference to hide it.

So, how can I hide the ColumnFilter?